# A special type of linear regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Usually linear regression involves two variables $(x,y)$, i.e. an independent variable $x$ and a dependent variable $y$, and they are related by the following expression
\begin{equation}
y = a_0 + a_1 x,
\end{equation}
where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are parameters that define the linear model. In linear regression we have one equation of this form for each couple of observed variables $(x_i,y_i)$, thus we have a linear system and its solution gives us $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Let's consider that we have two set of independent-dependent variables, namely $(x,y)$ and $(w,z)$. The first two variables $(x,y)$ are related by the previous equation, while the second two variables $(w,z)$ are related by the following
\begin{equation}
z = b_0 + b_1 w,
\end{equation}
where $b_0$ and $b_1$ are parameters that define the linear relation between $z$ and $w$. Also in this case a set of observation $(w_j,z_j)$ leads to a linear system and its solution gives us $b_0$ and $b_1$.

In general, if $a_0$, $a_1$, $b_0$ and $b_1$ are independent, then we can solve the two linear systems separately. But now, let's suppose that $a_0$ and $b_0$ are independent, while $a_1=b_1$. In this case, the two linear systems should be solved simultaneously.

I've solved this problem just definying one linear system of equation involving both the two sets of equations, but I would like to know if this problem has a specific name and how to correctly approach it. In particular, I want to know how to assessing the fit quality (for example, with an equivalent of the $R^2$).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model is $$y=a_0+c_1x,\\z=b_0+c_1w$$ you can minimize

$$\sum(a_0+c_1x-y)^2+\sum(b_0+c_1w-z)^2,$$

giving the equations

$$\sum a_0+c_1x-y=0,\\\sum b_0+c_1w-z=0,\\\sum x(a_0+c_1x-y)+\sum w(b_0+c_1w-z)=0.$$

Now solve this $3\times3$ system for $a_0,b_0,c_1$.

The fit quality is still given by the ratio of the explained variance over the total variance.

Comment: Well, I have solved the problem in a similar way, namely accorpating the two linear systems, defining the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ of the whole system, the unknown vector $\vec{p} = (a_0.b_0,c_1)^T$ and the vector $\vec{q}=(y_1,y_2,\dots,z_1,z_2,\dots)^T$. So that the whole system becames $\vec{q}=\boldsymbol{A}\vec{p}$ and I can solve it with LLS $\vec{p}=(\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A})^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}^T\vec{q}$. But how can I evaluate the fit in this case? How can I calculate a coefficient of determination $R^2$ for the fitting? Can you show the formula, please?